# How to update the configuration files in WAS Liberty once after deployment Can it not be like Tomcat web server?

Tags: websphere-liberty

After deploying WAR file in WAS Liberty container, I try to edit one of the configuration file under “WEB-INF” folder by stopping and again restarting the WAS liberty server. However, I  cannot use updated information and it uses the old configuration which was used during initial deployment.

Answer (score 2):

If you put `.war` it is automatically expanded each time the server starts. However you can also use 'expanded deployment' and put unpacked .war to the apps folder. In that case you will be able to modify files on the fly without rewrites during restarts. Check this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep.html) for more details.

Comment: Gas is right, expanded applications should help here. To use this make sure `<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>` is in your server.xml (it gets added by default, but may have been removed)

Answer (score 0):

Continue with this issue ... and thank you for your replies for this question.
I am looking for solution where it will unpack WAR file automatically like tomcat,WAS,etc… and we can update and use the information after this WAR extraction.

I checked autoexpand option and made it false. Now after making this changes, WAR file is not getting extracted in the apps folder.

Actually, we can use this solution as workaround i.e. need to enable the auto expand option in the server.xml. This will expand/extract the WAR file. Then need to stop the Liberty server. Now, update server.xml and disable the auto expand option. After that we need to update the required configuration file. Then need to start the server. This actually work, but this cannot be solution.

I am looking for solution like tomcat web server, where after deploying war file, we can make changes inside webapps/xx/WEB-INF/ path for further configuration settings.

Comment: I really dont see any difference, just instead copying war file to the directory, you are unzipping that file to directory. Just like changing `cp` command to 'unzip` command. In general, for production it is not recommended to change single files at random times, but follow some devops process. For DEV, you can actually work with 'free form' of the project, where it is already extracted and you can change any files, without the need of building `war` at all.

Comment: So please describe what you are trying to accomplish as maybe there is just different way that will fulfill your needs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply!!

Please find the requirement details.

WAR file is deployed @ /opt/Liberty/wlp/usr/servers/TCLiberty/apps/

-rw-r--r-- 1 clsqa cls 43358874 Apr  5 17:21 TC-DEV-4.3.war

This file will get extracted @ /opt/Liberty/wlp/usr/servers/TCLiberty/apps/expanded/

/opt/Liberty/wlp/usr/servers/TCLiberty/apps/expanded>ls

drwxr-x--- 10 clsqa cls 4096 Apr 11 14:53 TC-DEV-4.3.war

/opt/Liberty/wlp/usr/servers/TCLiberty/apps/expanded>ls -ltr TC-DEV-4.3.war
total 60
-rw-r-----  1 clsqa cls  1555 Feb 28 01:53 index.html
drwxr-x---  3 clsqa cls  4096 Apr 11 14:53 ..
drwxr-x---  2 clsqa cls  4096 Apr 11 14:53 META-INF
drwxr-x---  9 clsqa cls  4096 Apr 11 14:53 images
drwxr-x---  2 clsqa cls  4096 Apr 11 14:53 logs
drwxr-x---  8 clsqa cls  4096 Apr 11 14:53 WEB-INF
drwxr-x---  3 clsqa cls  4096 Apr 11 14:53 css
drwxr-x---  2 clsqa cls 12288 Apr 11 14:53 html
drwxr-x--- 10 clsqa cls  4096 Apr 11 14:53 .
drwxr-x---  2 clsqa cls 12288 Apr 11 14:53 js
drwxr-x---  2 clsqa cls  4096 Apr 11 14:53 pdf

## The WAR file extraction was done automatically since we have made auto expand = true

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="9080"
              httpsPort="9443"
              host="*" />

<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
<webApplication contextRoot="TC-DEV-4.3" location="TC-DEV-4.3.war" />
<mimeTypes>
<type>.htc=text/x-component</type>
</mimeTypes>
```

Now my requirement is to make changes in file which is available in “/opt/Liberty/wlp/usr/servers/TCLiberty/apps/expanded/TC-DEV-4.3.war/WEB-INF/”

/opt/Liberty/wlp/usr/servers/TCLiberty/apps/expanded/TC-DEV-4.3.war/WEB-INF>ls TMS.properties
-rw-r----- 1 clsqa cls 2789 Apr  2  2010 TMS.properties

## Content of this file are some predefined variables (constants)and ip address(variable) of the application and corresponding port. This IP address is always different which need to modified depending upon the application server and ports of the environment

## appaddrlist=//:

In order to make this files changes, I need to stop the Liberty server. But when I restart the server again, the existing WAR file will be extracted in the “expanded” path. And I lose my changes.

Now, as per our discussion and solution provided, I can make server.xml file and make changes of autoexpand option to false. In this case TMS.property file will not be overwritten and my issue is resolved.

However, I believe this solution as workaround because every time I need to modify the server.xml file.

Is there any other solution? Earlier I had given reference of the tomcat web server where we can make changes in the WEB-INF folder after auto extraction by tomcat server.

Request to guide in this regards.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please guide here?